# How to sort by domain name using SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have two tables:

1. `Contact` (columns are: ContactId, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress)
2. `Address` (columns are: ContactId, AddressLine1, City, CountryCode)

Some `EmailAddresses` have multiple ContactId, FirstName, LastName and AddressLine1

I'm trying to get a list of DISTINCT EmailAddress and ANY name/details related to that email address.

I'm ALSO trying to SORT all email addresses by domain name (eg; all gmail.com together, all Hotmail.com together and so on)

My code so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(EmailAddress),
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    AD.AddressLine1, AD.City, AD.CountryCode
FROM 
    [Contact] C
INNER JOIN 
    Address AD ON C.ContactId = AD.ContactId
WHERE 
    (set of conditions)
-------Code works fine until here but sorting by domain name doesn't work---
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING(EMailAddress,(CHARINDEX('@', EMailAddress) + 1), 1)
```

Error message I get is:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: Well, it *looks* like you're trying to apply `DISTINCT` only to the e-mail address, and that's not how it works (it applies to *all* columns). Do you really have the potential for exact duplicates here? Can two different contact IDs really have the same e-mail address? And the same address? Have you tried simply removing the `DISTINCT`, which would allow you to order by things not in the select list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per email, use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName,
             AD.AddressLine1, AD.City, AD.CountryCode,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmailAddress ORDER BY EmailAddress) as seqnum
      FROM [Contact] C INNER JOIN
            Address AD
           ON C.ContactId = AD.ContactId
      WHERE (set of conditions)
    -------Code works fine until here but Sorting by domain name doesn't 
     ) x
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(EMailAddress,(CHARINDEX('@', EMailAddress) + 1), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, using derived table

```
 select distinct * 
 from (
 SELECT EmailAddress
      ,SUBSTRING(EMailAddress,(CHARINDEX('@',EMailAddress)+1),1) [Domain]
      ,FirstName
      ,LastName
      ,AD.AddressLine1
      ,AD.City
      ,AD.CountryCode

FROM [Contact] C
INNER JOIN Address AD ON C.ContactId = AD.ContactId
 ) x
 order by domain
```

Comment: This is great but I'm not sure why I'm getting duplicate names and Email addresses with this. Only the AddressLine1 and City are different.

Comment: @user1777929 If you're getting duplicates that sounds like a data issue, not a query syntax issue.

Comment: @user1777929  post your Contact data order by contact id.

Comment: and also your address table order by contact id

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT  distinct 
        c.EmailAddress
        , c.SUBSTRING(EMailAddress,(CHARINDEX('@',EMailAddress)+1),1) AS [Domain]
        , c.FirstName
        , c.LastName
        , ad.AddressLine1
        , ad.City
        , ad.CountryCode
FROM    Contacts c
JOIN    Address ad
        on c.ContactId = ad.ContactId
GROUP   
BY      c.EmailAddress
        , c.SUBSTRING(EMailAddress,(CHARINDEX('@',EMailAddress)+1),1)
        , c.FirstName
        , c.LastName
        , ad.AddressLine1
        , ad.City
        , ad.CountryCode
ORDER 
BY      c.SUBSTRING(EMailAddress,(CHARINDEX('@',EMailAddress)+1),1)
```